# Firebase MLKit fails to build due to META-INF file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

In upgrading my dependencies to the latest:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common:16.1.6"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.2.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.2"
```

My build failed with the following exception:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlkit:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface.version'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You can safely add the following to your the `android {}` block of your app's `build.gradle` file to ignore these files:

```
android {
  //
  // ...
  //
  packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface.version'
      exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but would you mind explaining why? Maybe linking somewhere? It doesn't feel like something we should do forever.